How to clear ajax header requests from network tab using Jquery
How to hide the Ajax header data from the browser's network tab?
I want to hide the authorization token from the header, which is displayed in the browser's network tab.

You can't. But why do you need to? The token is only visible to the user who is sending the request, and - presumably - this token is unique to them anyway. So why does it matter? If you're using a HTTPS connection then the header cannot be viewed by anyone after it leaves the browser, until it arrives at the target server. The whole point of the Network tool is to allow you to debug such requests easily and safely. This sounds like a question based on a misunderstanding. Please explain exactly why you think you need to do this.

I'm about 99% sure there's no API that lets you do that. Moreover, the user could easily find the authorization token even if you did. Remember: Nothing you send to the client is private from the user. If you need something to be kept from the user, don't send it to them.
